# How does the ADO pipeline definition versioning work?

Tags: azure-pipelines

1. Pipeline YAML files are part of our repo
2. We deploy from a single trunk branch

Problem: A later commit overrode the pipeline definition of a previous commit.

We first ran a pipeline for a commit (call it #1) in our trunk. The pipeline deployed to dev & test successfully. Before we ran #1's pipeline run to UAT, we deployed a new commit (call it #2) to dev. The new commit (#2) contained a pipeline definition change in the YAML. We then ran our previous pipeline (#1) to UAT, and it tried to execute the later commits (#2) YAML pipeline changes.

Is this a bug? are their best practices for this scenario?

This was unexpected behaviour and would have expected the pipelines definition to respect the commits snapshot of the pipeline allowing us to run historical pipelines against the version of the pipeline definition that was committed at that time.

---

[Visual representation of pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUwap.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you ran the "previous" pipeline? When you were queuing the pipeline, what did you do? Is there only a single pipeline? Is your pipeline consuming any other repositories?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, hopefully the visual I've added will make more sense. Thanks

Comment: This post seems to suggest a similar root cause for the above (although describing a different scenario) https://andrewlock.net/handling-concurrent-merges-to-master-in-multi-stage-azure-devops-pipelines/

Answer (score -1):

Azure Pipeline is a CI/CD tool to build your source code. Thus, if the two pipelines as you mentioned are built for the same repo same branch, and you already do a new commit (call it #2) to the branch, you can't run the pipeline for previous commit (like #1) unless you convert the code change back to commit #1.

All the builds are history of pipeline run, rerun previous build will run the pipeline with current definition and source code.

You can run the pipeline for different branches with different version of source code and pipeline change in the YAML. For example, branch1's latest change is commit #1, branch2's latest change is commit #2. After deployed the new commit #2 to dev with branch2, you can run pipeline for commit #1 with branch1. Refer to[Version control systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops#version-control-systems) for more information.